# Is it possible to log whenever someone decrypts a credit card in MSSQL 2012?

Tags: sql-server-2012, trigger, encryption

All of our credit cards are encrypted. The process to decrypt them is to Open the symmetric key and decrypt the data by certificate.

Is it possible to add a trigger on something in the process to ensure that this is logged to a table?

For example: Trigger when the below is executed

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY KEYNAME
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE CERT_NAME;
GO
SELECT cc_card_number, AS 'Decrypted Credit Card Number'
FROM dbo.clever_lead_master
WHERE lead_id in ('6123009','6756089','6123012', '6605155')

 -- Close the symmetric key
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY CC_SYMMETRIC_2019;
GO
```

e.g. trigger:

```
INSERT INTO pci_log (event_time, lead_id, [description], who)
(SELECT getdate(), lead_id, 'cc_encrypt', user FROM clever_lead_master
WHERE lead_id in (select lead_id from inserted))
```

Comment: SQL Audit can handle this I think? Or 1. Create a (signed? execute as owner?) stored procedure that accepts the list of `lead_id` values as a table-valued parameter (and also logs execution). 2. Grant execute on the stored procedure to the user(s). 3. Deny direct read access to the table. If they want the data, they'll have to go through the stored procedure. This sounds hard but, yeah, with storing credit card information, there is some responsibility to control/prevent access, and sometimes that takes work. (Also, make sure the users don't have access to whatever table you log to.)